# Pentaho job FTP is not picking up file from remote location

Tags: pentaho, firewall, system-administration, pentaho-spoon

Hello I have a Pentaho job that is running fine from 2 years. This job picks the files from remote location and places it in local directory. All of a sudden from past ten days it is not picking up the file from the FTP location (remote). The error i get is "ignoring the set locale". Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably something changed in server side. Take a look here: http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?142190-Pentaho-Data-Integration-FTP-Issue

Comment: Hi, I have gone through that post but it didn't solve the problem.